# Java String comparison is not working

Tags: java, string-comparison

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Hi I AM ";
        String a1 = "Hi I AM";
        if (a1.equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
            System.out.println("equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not equal");
        }
    }
```

Why above code is displaying not equal in console?

Comment: There's extra witespace in string 'a' Use a.replace(" ","") to compare string ignoring whitespace.

Comment: Now that you have corrected the code , it should print 'equal' . So what more?

Comment: Now also it is printing not equal

Comment: Are you sure you are using same code as above . I ran it and It prints 'equal' .

Comment: can you take a snapshot and upload an image of the error you are facing ??

Comment: Try printing Unicode Table indexes of characters from your strings. To do this you can use `for (char ch : yourString.toCharArray()){System.out.println((int)ch);}`. It is probable that one of your Strings contain some non printable characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first String has an additional space at the end, so it's not equal to the second String.

Comment: I removed extra spaces but still it is showing not equal in the console (eclipse)

Comment: @YosuvaA Perhaps some of the spaces are not the same character in the too Strings. You should try to print the int value of each character - `for int i=0;i<a.length();i++) System.out.println((int)a.charAt(i));` See what you get for i==2 and i==4.

Answer (score 0):

it will display "not equal" because you have added an extra space in `a`(which is not equal to `a1`).

```
String a="Hi I AM "; // has extra space in the end(8 characters)
String a1="Hi I AM"; //this string has 7 characters
```

Edit:
it actually works fine after your edit to the question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Better to use trim() method for removing the unwanted white spaces in leading and tailing positions of the string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String a="Hi I AM";
            String a1="Hi I AM";
            if(a1.equalsIgnoreCase(a.trim()))
            {
                System.out.println("equal");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("not equal");
            }
```

See the result:

[image]

Comment: Now also it is printing not equal

Comment: [Works for me is not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid). It is comment representing that we can't reproduce OP problem.

Comment: @ Pshemo, Agreed with you